# Android - StickyGridHeaders GridView Image Display

Tags: android, gridview

I have downloaded the StickGridHeaders and modified it to sort an arraylist that i get from internet,also changed the item xml so each cell will show an image instead of texview.

The Problem :

Images are not loaded until i scroll up and down,like something happen onScroll function that show the images,so any help to fix that and show the images directly after loaded?

This is my simple adatper getView code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgGridBird);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> myHash = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myHash = StringArray.get(position);

    HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);
    if(ClassName.contains("Birds")){
        if(Language.equals("ar")){
            if (item.get("ArabicName") instanceof CharSequence) {
                holder.textView.setText((CharSequence) myHash.get("ArabicName"));
            } else {
                holder.textView.setText(item.get("ArabicName").toString());
            }
        }else{
            if (item.get("EnglishName") instanceof CharSequence) {
                holder.textView.setText((CharSequence) myHash.get("EnglishName"));
            } else {
                holder.textView.setText(item.get("EnglishName").toString());
            }
        }
        ImageLoaderNoResize.DisplayImage(myHash.get("ThumbImagePath"), holder.imageView);
    }else{
        if(Language.equals("ar")){
            if (item.get("ArabicType") instanceof CharSequence) {
                holder.textView.setText((CharSequence) myHash.get("ArabicName"));
            } else {
                holder.textView.setText(item.get("ArabicName").toString());
            }
        }else{
            if (item.get("EnglishType") instanceof CharSequence) {
                holder.textView.setText((CharSequence) myHash.get("EnglishName"));
            } else {
                holder.textView.setText(item.get("EnglishName").toString());
            }
        }
        ImageLoaderNoResize.DisplayImage(myHash.get("ThumbImagePath"), holder.imageView);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement any image loader in adapter for image loading.

Ref links
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-volley-library-example/